# C# Outlook Remove event when email sent successfully?

Tags: c#, email, events, outlook

I have a plugin outlook, I create an event when an email sent successfully, this code:

```
private Outlook.Items _items;
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.Application application = this.Application;
    _items = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items;
    _items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Items_ItemAdd);
}
```

Then, I have the user setting, and if the user doesn't select, I want to remove that event (Items_ItemAdd).

So should I do?

Comment: You might want to get the settings changed event and perform unsubscribe -= or subscribe += accordingly. Also, you might need to include settings option condition in ThisAddIn_Startup and need to program ThisAddIn_Shutdown also to unsubscribe -= on exit.

Comment: I used -= when user change setting, but not work?

Comment: Why not simply set a flag that your code in Items_ItemAdd will use to determine whether it needs to do work or just bail out?

Comment: `I used -= when user change setting, but not work?` I would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, tracking the `Sent Items` folder is not really a good idea. Outlook allows to remove a sent item by skipping the `Sent Items` folder. The [DeleteAfterSubmit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-deleteaftersubmit-property-outlook) property of Outlook items is a Boolean value that is True if a copy of the mail message is not saved upon being sent, and False if a copy is saved in Sent Items folder. So, you will never get the event fired if users or other software like VBA macros or add-ins set this property before sending emails.

A better way is to handle the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-newmailex-event-outlook) event of the Application which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox.

This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem` , `MeetingItem` , or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Note that this behavior has changed from earlier versions of the event when the `EntryIDCollection` contained a list of comma-delimited Entry IDs of all the items received in the Inbox since the last time the event was fired.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getitemfromid-method-outlook) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously. You should not assume that after these events fire, you will always get a one-item increase in the number of items in the Inbox.

In the `NewMailEx` event handler you may ask users whether to process emails after sending and, if it is not, you can simply set the [DeleteAfterSubmit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-deleteaftersubmit-property-outlook) property to true.